# Strange noises when using brakes

Tags: wheels, spokes, noise, brake-noise

Im pretty much devastated already. The wheel making this strange scritching noises when I use my brakes.

If I block the wheel by brakes and move the wheel back and forth, it will sound the same.

The noise is like when a metal piece fits in some place, then goes back and fits another.

The culprit is the wheel itself, we put another wheel and noises disappeared.

Any advices, what can I check? No repair man can understand what the culprit is.

The front wheel is mavic, with aero spokes.

I've made a video of the noice and how I make it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-8mir36AAlw3gkYkKCYsnbJCZK06ffbr/view

---

There is a 15mm through-axle, not a quick-release.

---

**Edit 07.18:**
I've made another video showing more details about the problem, please check it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-JQWkXHByyHZIkXyflTdmU1DsBcV-ttA/view?usp=sharing

**Not sure if the disc is the issue.** When I block the brakes and rotate the wheel, the disc moves naturally(as pads move) and then stops.

When I continue rotating the wheel, the disc is not moving(I'm 90% sure of it).

Rotor is installed correctly.

**About spokes :** I "guitared" (if that what you mean by plunking) every spoke - some of them feel natural, some loose.

The rim is damaged, the guy made everything to make it true as much as possible

Also, as you can see, I can make the noice by rotating wheel by spokes, not the wheel. I did that for every spoke combination - nothing.

**Bearings:** I like this idea. But as for me, bearing look stiff and all. However the clicking sound seems like coming from the inside of the hub. I've tried to disassemble it, there was a C shaped washer that keeps the bearings inside. I've stopped there, but I think I can manage to proceed.

Also, I've tighten the axle thread as much as possible, but no luck.

PS: I know that wheel is a garbage, but I'm broke and curious!

PSS: Don't afraid to make an answer, so I can comment on it, that would be easier to communicate. Thank you all.

I found a video

with the same problem as mine. The guy says the hub is a culprit!

Comment: Check the spokes. Are there any loose ones or crossovers that might be rubbing weirdly

Comment: Can you tell us the exact model of the wheel? And can you make a short video of the problem?

Comment: @WarrenBurton how do I check this? I've touched crossings and end nuts of spokes with my finger and everything seems stiff and ok. Maybe there is another way?

Comment: that pinging sound has to be coming from the spokes, but it's not necessarily the spoke exciting it.  In the video it looks like you've got a bit of stick-slip in the brakes, but I assume that's just modulating them to allow you to slip the wheel.  I would be making sure the wheel is true because with that spoke count a loose spoke will put the wheel out of true (also check the rotor isn't warped or contaminated, though the video suggests that's not the problem).

Comment: Try plucking the spokes and listening - the pitch should be very close.  You'll need to find the best spot for your cross pattern to get a good ring, and pluck in that spot for all of them

Comment: I see definite witness-marks on the rotor suggesting that it its scored - is that correct?   You're also sending the brake lever right to the bars - I'd expect it to bite earlier and then be progressive.   The twang sounds like spokes resonating, but the cause of that seems to be the sliding in the brake pads.    Is the rotor mounted in the right way?  Look for writing indicating a direction of travel.  Measure the rotor's thickness too, and runout if you can.  Compare with the "quiet" wheel.   Great work on the writeup too.

Comment: Did it always make this kind of noise from new, or did it start suddenly, or slowly get worse over time ?   How worn are your pads and pad spring?

Comment: My DT Swiss PR 1400 DICUT® OXiC (rim brake) rear wheel makes a similar noise when I accelerate or climb in an easy gear or just step on the pedals with the rear wheel locked. I couldn’t find the culprit and so far it’s still going strong after >10Mm. The spoke tension is fine.

Comment: Guys, thank you all for your answers! I've updated my question, please check it! I need your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A supposition: that may only be applicable for Mavic wheels with 'QRM SL' bearings. The bearings preload for these wheels is done when tightening the wheel, with the QR lever or thru-axle. If the preload is not sufficient, you'll have play in the bearings, which may explain this noise. With the rotor blocked, moving the wheel can create some unwanted vibration in the hub that are then propagated and create this noise.

So, if you have QRM SL bearings, and you notice play in the bearings, try tightening the wheel a bit more and see if it still happens.

Comment: I like this idea. I've updated my answer a bit. Please check it out! Should I disassemble the hub? Thanks!